# __FILE__ can be referred by const char* in C++?

Tags: c++, macros

I have a question after reading memTrack library linked from http://www.almostinfinite.com/memtrack.html

Can `__FILE__` be saved in a variable with type `const char*` ***forever*** and don't need to use `strdup()`? Doesn't `BlockHeader::Stamp` use `strdup()` to assign the `__FILE__` string?

---

```
void BlockHeader::Stamp(char const *filename, int lineNum, char const *typeName)
{
    myFilename = filename; // don't use strdup(filename) to assign?
    myLineNum = lineNum;
    myTypeName = typeName;
}
```

---

Give an example to continue to describe my question:

```
    //testFILE.cpp
    #include <iostream>

    const char* getStr()
    {
        return __FILE__; 
    }

    void Print()
    {
        std::cout << __FILE__ << std::endl;
    }

    int main()
    {
        std::cout << getStr() << std::endl;
        Print();

        return 0;
    }
```

after testing, the binary testFILE can print two lines of "testFILE.cpp". Is it coincidence only?

Comment: I've stressed the _**forever**_ as it looks to me the principal interrogation.

Comment: An interesting question, congratulations

Answer (score 10):

`__FILE__` gets expanded to a string literal at preprocessing time. If you put

```
const char* getStr()
{
    return __FILE__; 
}
```

in `testFILE.cpp`, then it's exactly as if you'd written

```
const char* getStr()
{
    return "testFILE.cpp";
}
```

and the same rules that apply to all string literals also apply to string literals that are the result of expanding `__FILE__`: the strings they point to exist for the whole run of the application.

Answer (score 5):

`__FILE__` expands to a string literal. You can store a pointer to (the first character) of a string literal in a variable of type `char const*`. The literal's lifetime is the same as the program execution.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all. I got it.

The string literal in C/C++ is saved in static data segment, so the literal's lifetime is the same as the program execution.

I was confused the string literal with local variable.

Thanks again.